# How to expire data in Firebase Database

Tags: firebase, database-design, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, nosql

I am building an "events" application, in which some users put some events in the application and other users see them. Let's say every event has a start datetime, end datetime and name.

I would like the users to see only the current events, that is the events with start < now < end. This is some kind of filtering, which is not supported in Firebase. I can achieve this in my application with startAt and endAt queries. However, this will not help me to hide this confidential data from the users because, although my application won't access past and future events, anyone can query the database from its REST API to see these events.

Therefore, I decided to structure the data with three lists of events: `past_events`, `current_events` and `future_events`.

Now, the problem is that, I need to move the events from `future_events` to  `current_events` and from `current_events` to `past_events` when the time is right. I believe there is no way to trigger these changes automatically within firebase. Therefore, I am considering to put a service somewhere which periodically does this cleaning up.

Is this the best way to handle data expiration in Firebase? Any suggestions/comments?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to consider changing your design in that 'moving' data to 'clean it up' is usually not necessary if the Firebase structure is set up correctly. For example, when running a query, return only those results where the timestamp stored in that node is greater than 7 days ago. That way you don't need to worry about 'expiring' data as the code handles it for you. Or return result for nodes where the timestamp is seven days from now. All done in code and Firebase Rules would limit users from getting to any other data.

Comment: @Jay, well, the ```code handles that for you``` part is the same as @Pawel Janicki's answer and again, the problem is, it hides the data from the application user but when you go and query the database directly (via Postman for example), you can see all events.

Relying on the application-side queries do not provide security over the database. I want these data to be confidential so no-one, (including script kiddies) should see that. This can only be achieved via security rules and security rules don't provide filtering.

Answer (score -1):

If you have the end datetime for each event, saved in Firebase, you can then query Firebase only for results that are active.

Example in JavaScript:

```
var date = new Date();
var currentTime = date.getTime();
var ref = firebase.database().ref("events");
var result = ref.orderByChild("endtime").startAt(currentTime);
```

Firebase documentation for Query: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#startAt

When it comes to cleaning up the database, as you mentioned, there is no way to do it automatically within firebase (as far as I know), so if you want to avoid cleaning the database by hand, it's a good idea to write an external service to do this.

Comment: Querying solves the problem for the application but my problem is to force this in database level. When you don't hide the data in database level and rely on querying, anyone can query the Firebase API manually to see the events that you don't want them to see.

Comment: Sure, I facing the same problem with my app. The only way, I guess, is to add some sort of backend for your app, which will be connected to the same Firebase database and will do all the logic. So it can be bind to the database and periodically check the timestamp and move events between the lists, accordingly.

Comment: @AhmetErenBaşak How would 'anyone' query your data? If you set up [Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) then only users that meet that criteria can access the data.

Comment: @Jay, with rules, one can define whether a user can query the data or not. However, they cannot be used for filtering the data. For example, if I have an `events` object which stores all events in that object, then I can set up the rules so that specific users can see all events under it or none. It is not possible to set rules so that users can see only the current events.

Comment: @AhmetErenBaşak I am not suggesting to filter the content with rules as that is not what rules are for. However, you can use rules to deny access to nodes. The more important question is how would 'anyone' query the Firebase API manually? Once that is understood a more thorough answer can be crafted. Can you possibly update the initial question as to why and how that's an issue?

Comment: @Jay I have added why and how anyone can query the database directly. Basically, since Firebase provides a REST API, when you send a GET request to `<database>.firebaseio.com/events/`, you get all objects under the `events` object.